# How to completely remove google maps marker clickable area on mobile web?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, mobile, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Basically I have a map where users can tap to place markers. But when there already is a marker on the map, and I try to place one nearby, the marker intercepts the click event, so the map cannot receive it and place another marker. I have `clickable` set to false and I have created no listeners for the markers.

This is only an issue on mobile - I fixed it on desktop by setting the shape of the marker to a 0 by 0 px rectangle:

```
shape: {
  type: 'rect',
  coords: [0,0,0,0]
}
```

This "shape" property only works on desktop - when I load the page with the chrome developer tools device emulator thing, the HTML `area` element that sets the clickable area is not there.
Instead, there is just a `div` element and an `img` element on the marker. If I set the height and width of these elements to 0 (with inspect element), the map is able to receive click events on the marker! But I don't know how to do that with CSS or Javascript because I see no way to access those elements.

The problem seems to be that when google maps detects a mobile device, it listens for click events through the marker `img` element. On desktop, it creates an `area` element that takes clicks. So is there any way I can edit the heights and widths of elements that the maps API creates? Or is there any other way I can set the clickable area of a marker on mobile?

[Minimum reproducible example](https://jsfiddle.net/c2t3bmp0/3/)

To emulate my problem, press ctrl+shift+I and then ctrl+shift+M, then where it says "Responsive" select any mobile device (iPad is best since it's easier to navigate). Reload the page. Tap the map to place a marker and then tap that marker. You can then turn off dev tools, reload the page, and try placing two markers again to see what's supposed to happen.

Comment: That sounds like it might be a bug in the Google Maps JavaScript API v3, if I understand your question. Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Done. I have also figured out the issue in the process - if I remove the marker title, it works.

Comment: @geocodezip By the way, is there a way to create a google maps example in jsfiddle without using my API key?

Comment: If you start from one of Google's examples, they provide a working key.  There is also a key that works in [StackSnippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remove this line:

`title: 'markertitle',`

Everything works fine. For some reason adding a title to the marker creates an element on top of it that intercepts clicks.

Comment: I still believe that is a bug and should be reported in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/558438) (unless it already is there) with a link to this question.

Comment: Looks like it is there already: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/151092019